# WCF Parallel Impersonation

Tags: c#, wcf, impersonation, parallel-extensions

I have a WCF service with "ImpersonationOption.Required".  The impersonation does not seem to flow through when using parallelism.  For example:

```
Parallel.ForEach(items => results.Add(SystemUtil.WindowsUser.Name)
```

Will return a number with the impersonated user, and a number with the app pool user.  Can impersonation be made to work with parallelism?

Best,

Marc

**Update:**

This is actual code on the IIS Service side.

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
public string[] WhoAmI(int numOfTests)
{
    var tests = new List<int>();
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfTests; i++)
        tests.Add(i);

    var results = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
    Parallel.ForEach(tests, (test) => results.Add(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(false).Name));
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

If I pass in numOfTests = 10, it spawns 10 tasks and return the WindowsIndentity Name of each task.  What I get is ~70% "IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.0" and ~30% me.

How can I set it such that my identity always makes it into the Parallel.ForEach?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post exact code, this makes no sense.

Comment: I have updated the issue with exact code.

Comment: Re-write this as a normal For each loop (`foreach(timer in timers) { results.Add(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(false).Name; }`) and you will see the problem, You never do anything with `timer` inside the loop so you are just executing the same code over and over again so of course you will get the same result each time.

Comment: OK, much better question this way and even interesting. If it doesn't reopen in a day or so, re-post.

Comment: As an explanation I would say that the main thread is doing part of the ForEach, impersonated, and that extra Threads do not impersonate. The number 10 is too small to get a real distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take care of that yourself. Try something like this:

```
IntPtr token = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;

Parallel.ForEach( Enumerable.Range( 1, 100 ), ( test ) =>
{
    using ( WindowsIdentity.Impersonate( token ) )
    {
          Console.WriteLine( WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent( false ).Name );
    }
} );
```

Comment: This worked -- thanks!  We were lucky that we wrap Parallel.ForEach calls into an extension method so I only had to change in one place.