# Config IIS or ASP.NET to Use 'Login user' in Parallelism rather than 'IIS APPPOOL\\MyAppPool' User

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a web site in ASP.NET 4 that need Connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 with Parallelism, Also Use IIS 7 and Windows authentication, I use `Parallel.Foreach` expression, When I use `Foreach` every thing is fine, but in `Parallel.Foreach` I get an error: `Login failed for user: 'IIS APPPOOL\\MyAppPool'.`, So after some search I found need to change Process Model identity in Application pool From `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalSystem`:

[image]

Or I can add specific user:

[image]

But the last one is not a proper solution.

So I check in SQL SPs modified it and add line:

[image]

Then the result is: When I use `foreach` (mean without parallelism) all the registered user is `MyLoginUser` but with `Parallel.foreach` (And `LocalSystem` Identity) the first user registered is `MyLoginUser` and the others is `NT Authority System`.

Also I found [Parallel Impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395819/wcf-parallel-impersonation) but not worked either and I got the same error.

As I understand `MyLoginUser` have not permission to Multi Connect to sql, Am I right?

if yes, so how can I add permission to this user?

In final I try to use `ApplicationPoolIdentity` and `MyLoginUser` to use Parallelism to connect to SQL. Does any one have any suggestion?

**UPDATE:**

I found that the first connection to db is the `MyLoginUser` then the ASP.NET try to connect more and let ApplicationPool do this, but the applicationpool can not login because have not permission and I also don't want to let it, the only user could connect must be `myloginuser`.

So the question could be:

How config **IIS** or **ASP.NET** to use `myloginuser` (the same of first user) 
to connect with all connections to db (also in Parallel connections)?